# .NET SSH pbrun su

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssh, ssh.net

I'm connecting to a linux server from my .net application using SSH.NET.  Each command that I execute completes as expected with the exception of pbrun su - myaccount.

While debugging, when the pbrun su - myaccount command is executed, the arrow in the debugger disappears and control is never returned to visual studio, thus requiring me to manually stop debugging the application.

Comment: The `su` command is probably waiting for a password. If you are looking at stdout you wont see this, because the prompt  `Password:` is send to stderr. In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079526/how-to-write-to-stdin-read-from-stdout-of-an-ssh-connected-remote-process-renc#36360010) post you can se haw to write to shell stdin.

Comment: @AxelWass Why would it be expecting a password if one isn't prompted for or required when running the same pbrun su command in the terminal?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but maybe the ssh user and the local user aren't the same? Maybe using `sudo visudo` helps as [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-prompt-password-for-sudo#470466).

Comment: I once saw pbrun asking "Reason for ID change:" in stdout and waiting for stdin input. Maybe this  is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that pbrun is asking for something in stdin (password, reason, etc) you can create a shell with streams controled by you and write in it.

Simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionInfo = new Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo("ancardia.us.to", "adom", "adom");
            var ssh = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connectionInfo);

            ssh.Connect();

           var shell = ssh.CreateShell(Console.OpenStandardInput(), Console.OpenStandardOutput(), Console.OpenStandardOutput());
           shell.Start();

       while (true) {
            Console.Read();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've used your example with my server details and it shows the remote terminal in the console.  However, as explained before, when I execute the pbrun su - myaccount, it changes user successfully and no password is required,